# Multiple radio button get selected in custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I am trying to list all installed applications using custom listview. Each row contains ImageView, TextView and RadioButton. The problem is when I click any radio button, more than one radio buttons get selected.

Code for my custom adapter and layout of row of listview is as below.

What is wrong in my code? Any help is welcome.

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ListItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String TAG = "TAG";

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

        // Declare Variables
        View v = convertView;
        AppNamesViewHolder viewHolder;
        ListItem item = items.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"in convertview=null");
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new AppNamesViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else 
        {
            viewHolder = (AppNamesViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.appName.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());

        return v;
    }
}  
class AppNamesViewHolder 
{     
    public TextView appName;
    public ImageView imgIcon;
    public RadioButton radioBt;

    public AppNamesViewHolder(View base) 
    {  
        appName = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.tvAppName);
        imgIcon = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        radioBt = (RadioButton)base.findViewById(R.id.radio);
    }  
}
```

**list_item_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:text="AppName"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it happens when u scroll?

Comment: It is most certainly a recycling issue.

Comment: Yes, multiple buttons get selected at fix distance. e.g. every 7th radio button gets selected from the first I have selected, which I can see while scrolling.